# Redirect form to different URL based on select option element But not selected after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to have the form to redirect to another url if any of the options are selected apart from Option Then show selected Option.

Thank you in advance

```
 <html> 
    <head>      
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
  </head>
   <body>    
        <form method='post'>   
            <select id="selectbox">  
                <option value="index.html" selected>Home</option>
                <option value="?hello=about" >Abut Us</option>
                <option value="?hello=contact" >Contact Us</option>
                <option value="?hello=blog">Blog</option>   
            </select>   
        </form>  

   <script>
        $(function(){
          // bind change event to select
          $('#selectbox').bind('change', function () {
              var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
              if (url) { // require a URL
                  window.location = url; // redirect
              }
              return false;
          });
        });
    </script> 
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, do you have an problem with it?

Comment: When I select any option my code redirect But not show selected name in redirect page. Always show "home".

Comment: `window.location.href = url;`

Comment: That's because the page has been reloaded. You need to store the value selected somewhere, or read it from the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming your URLs have query strings such as "?hello=about", "?hello=xxx" etc. the following should work. Drop this code just after the selectbox bind method. Bear in mind that I've not tested this code.

```
var option = location.search.replace(/(^\?hello=[^&#]+).*?$/i, "$1");
$('#selectbox').val(option);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use

```
if (url) { // require a URL
    window.location.href = url; // redirect
}
```

Because in the options value you're not passing the complete URL.

Comment: Setting `window.location` is perfectly fine. OP has clarified the problem is that the value of the select is changing after the redirect.

Comment: Alright @ Rory. For OP's query I suggest him to not to redirect on another url, just set the form Action to to another file which OP want to show after redirect and then show selected values under $_POST. I suppose it will work instead of redirecting the form

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    // bind change event to select
    $('#selectbox').bind('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url) { // require a URL
            $( 'form' ).attr( 'action', url ).submit();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the form to do more than what is indicated in your question, otherwise this is just a basic jump navigation. If you DO have more data to transmit then window.location won't post that data from the form. You need to do the following:

```
$(function(){
    // bind change event to select
    $('#selectbox').bind('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url) { 
            // set the 'action' attribute to the
            // value of the url var and submit the form.
            $('form').attr('action', url).submit();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

});

Comment: I tried this but not working, When I select any option my code redirect But not show selected name in redirect page. Always show "home"